# App.config seems to be ignored

Tags: c#, app-config

I've this Class Library, as a result of a refactor action. 
I added an App.config file and added something like this:

```
<configuration>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="MyDatabase" connectionString="Data Source=server;Initial Catalog=database;User ID=userid;Password=password" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

But when I run the application, debugging learns me this is totally ignored. The immediate window tells me:

```
ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[0]
                 {data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true}
    base {System.Configuration.ConfigurationElement}: {data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true}
    ConnectionString: "data source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true"
    Key: "LocalSqlServer"
    Name: "LocalSqlServer"
    Properties: {System.Configuration.ConfigurationPropertyCollection}
    ProviderName: "System.Data.SqlClient"
```

I've checked generated config file in the bin directory and its contents are identical to the App.config.

I try to read the App.config using:

```
ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[Constants.Connections.DevConnection].ConnectionString
```

Nothing out of the ordinary I'd say, but what is going wrong?

Comment: Check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4472232/configuration-from-app-config-isnt-being-pulled-correctly/4472261#4472261

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This connectionString should be in the corresponding app.config of the exe that you are running.

Answer (score 8):

A class library doesn't get its own config; for an app named Foo.exe you need your configuration to be in Foo.exe.config. The exception here is web apps, where web.config is the naming convention.

Comment: What would be the correct way to handle connectionstrings for a DLL then?

Comment: Via a constructor or similar fashion?

Answer (score 0):

Is the file being copied to output?  Secondly the connection string should be accessible from the AssemblyName.Settings.Properties class which is generated from your code.